# Move files based on creation date

Tags: regex, linux, shell

I got a problem with the following command that moves files older than 13 days from /unpack to /storage as it should.

```
find /home/user/private/data/unpack/* -mtime +13 -exec mv {} /home/user/private/data/unpack/storage/ \;
```

But if i keep those files in the /storage folder organized in sub-folders the above command will move all those files from its folders back into /storage

I searched around for a way to exclude /storage completely from the find command and came a gross prune as a method. I´m still rather new to linux and regex, so still had no luck getting  it working myself.

Crossing fingers for a pro out there that got time to help out.

Comment: Maybe this can be solved by using rsync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (it's a single line without those ending `\` characters):

```
find /home/user/private/data/unpack/* \
     -mtime +13 \
     \( ! -regex '/home/user/private/data/unpack/storage/.*' \) \
     -exec mv {} /home/user/private/data/unpack/storage/ \;
```

Comment: I tried to use your code in a .sh script and it ran fine, but sadly the result is exactly the same as my own. Still moves any files in a sub directory folder to storage back to the storage folder.

Comment: So very, VERY awesome. Not only does it work perfectly, as a bonus it does not spam out the shell window as mine did. thanks alot for it Zsolt.

Answer (score 0):

Know this is an old post but did you try this

```
find /home/user/private/data/unpack/* -mtime +13 ! -path /home/user/private/data/unpack/storage/* -exec mv {} /home/user/private/data/unpack/storage/ \;
```

That should work.

Sorry didnt' catch other command worked